# OpenStack VM networking broken

Tags: networking, routes, virtual, openstack, virtual-network

Good morning all.

I have an old OpenStack server (IceHouse running on Ubuntu 12) that the networking is broken on. I can access the main host on it's external IP but none of the VMs on their internal or external IPs. I'm trying to fix the networking on this because one day it just stopped working and as I didn't set up the networking on this (an old friend did) and my networking isn't good.

So my OpenStack is setup as follows:

Physical Server - External IP + internal IP of 10.0.0.1
5 VMs inside the physical server - each with their own External IP + internal IP of 10.0.0.2/3/5/6/12 respectively

**brctl show**

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br100           8000.002590a623ea       no              eth0
                                                        vnet0
virbr0          8000.000000000000       yes
```

**cat /var/lib/libvirt/network/default.xml**

```
<networkstatus>
  <class_id bitmap='0-2'/>
  <floor sum='0'/>
  <network>
    <name>default</name>
    <uuid>1418323a-ec13-4ea0-b342-c3263e44c4c4</uuid>
    <forward mode='nat'>
      <nat>
        <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
      </nat>
    </forward>
    <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
    <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
      <dhcp>
        <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
      </dhcp>
    </ip>
  </network>
</networkstatus>
```

**ifconfig**

```
br100     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:a6:23:ea
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fea6:23ea/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:21253 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14720 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1346723 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:1655846 (1.6 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:a6:23:ea
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:21898 errors:0 dropped:68 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14881 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1828683 (1.8 MB)  TX bytes:1655116 (1.6 MB)
          Memory:fb920000-fb940000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:110260 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:110260 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:37015458 (37.0 MB)  TX bytes:37015458 (37.0 MB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:172.16.17.1  P-t-P:172.16.17.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:88:14:70:4d:e2
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a888:14ff:fe70:4de2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:588 (588.0 B)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:16:3e:24:da:f2
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc16:3eff:fe24:daf2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3849 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:13581 (13.5 KB)  TX bytes:356808 (356.8 KB)
```

**ip a | grep state**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br100 state UP qlen 1000
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
4: br100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
5: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN
6: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 100
8: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br100 state UNKNOWN qlen 500
```

**ip route** (X.X.X.X being the externally facing public IP)

```
default via X.X.X.254 dev br100  metric 100
10.0.0.0/24 dev br100  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1
X.X.X.0/24 dev br100  proto kernel  scope link  src X.X.X.X
172.16.17.0/24 via 172.16.17.2 dev tun0
172.16.17.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.17.1
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1
192.168.122.0/24 dev br100  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.222
```

I can't ping or SSH to a VM externally or internally e.g. 10.0.0.5 from 10.0.0.1 and when a VM boots e.g. 10.0.0.5 it shows this:

```
[....] Configuring network interfaces...Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2
Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eth0/fa:16:3e:24:da:f2
Sending on   LPF/eth0/fa:16:3e:24:da:f2
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK from 10.0.0.1
bound to 10.0.0.5 -- renewal in 50 seconds.

ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info+++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+
ci-info: | Device |  Up  |  Address  |      Mask     |     Hw-Address    |
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+
ci-info: |   lo   | True | 127.0.0.1 |   255.0.0.0   |         .         |
ci-info: |  eth0  | True |  10.0.0.5 | 255.255.255.0 | fa:16:3e:24:da:f2 |
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+
ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Route info++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info: +-------+-------------+----------+---------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: | Route | Destination | Gateway  |    Genmask    | Interface | Flags |
ci-info: +-------+-------------+----------+---------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: |   0   |   0.0.0.0   | 10.0.0.1 |    0.0.0.0    |    eth0   |   UG  |
ci-info: |   1   |   10.0.0.0  | 0.0.0.0  | 255.255.255.0 |    eth0   |   U   |
ci-info: +-------+-------------+----------+---------------+-----------+-------+
```

**virsh list**

```
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 3     instance-00000025              running
```

Can anyone help a network noob?

Comment: Those VMs are up? What hypervisor are you using? KVM? the command 'virsh list' what does returns?

Comment: For now I'm just starting up 1 VM out of the 5 that were working to test. The hypervisor is an OVH Dedicated Server running Ubuntu 12, OpenStack Icehouse. Have put edited the above for the output of virsh list as requested.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? What was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start looking at the configured security groups and see if ingress rules for icmp and tcp on port 22 are present to accept the connections.

By default Openstack security groups deny external traffic.

Comment: Under the default security group rules it shows the following: https://i.imgur.com/GiAsZ4e.png Is this right, wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, as per the attached rules, communication is not restricted as you have opened up all TCP/UDP ports and ICMP for 0.0.0.0/0 CIDR. So Security groups doesn't seem to be the culprit here.